# NLog logs only to one .log file

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I'm using NLog.Web.AspNetCore to makings logs, but Nlog logs only to one all with date .log file (allfile name in nlog.config).

There is my nlog.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog-AspNetCore.txt">

    <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    </extensions>

    <!-- the targets to write to -->
    <targets>
        <!-- write logs to file  -->

        <target xsi:type="File" name="request-time" 
                fileName="(absolute path)\Log\request-time.log"
                layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />

        <target xsi:type="File" name="exceptions" 
                fileName="(absolute path)\Log\nlog-all-exceptions-${shortdate}.log"
                layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
        
        <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" 
                fileName="(absolute path)\Log\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
                layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
    </targets>

    <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
    <rules>
        <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />
        <logger name="kurs_ASP_dotNET___Restaurant_API.Controllers.*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="exceptions" />
        <logger name="kurs_ASP_dotNET___Restaurant_API.Middleware.RequestTimeMiddleware" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="request-time" />

    </rules>
</nlog>
```

And there is my example file which trying logs error.

```
namespace kurs_ASP_dotNET___Restaurant_API.Services;

    public class RestaurantService : IRestaurantService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<RestaurantService> _logger;
    
        public RestaurantService(ILogger<RestaurantService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Restaurant with id: {id} DELETE action invoked");
            
            ...
        }
    }
```

This fragment of code should create "nlog-all-exceptions-${shortdate}.log" file and logs there every usage of .LogError

Comment: When troubleshooting NLog-LoggingRules, then it is recommended activate the [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) at Debug-level. Then you can see the dump of the LoggingRules-configuration, and the Logger-name being used and how it maps to the configured targets. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

you could make some changes such as logs level and file location for suit your local project.

```
<targets async="true">
    <!-- Define different file targets. -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="infoFile"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/info-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${level}|${logger}|${message}" />

    <target xsi:type="File" name="warnFile"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/warn-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${level}|${logger}|${message}" />

    <target xsi:type="File" name="errorFile"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/error-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${level}|${logger}|${message}" />

    <target xsi:type="File" name="allLog"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/all-log-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${level}|${logger}|${message}" />
</targets>

<rules>
    <!-- Define rules to write logs into separate files.-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" maxlevel="Info" writeTo="infoFile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" maxlevel="Warn" writeTo="warnFile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="errorFile" />

    <!-- write all levels info in a file-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allLog" />
</rules>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you may need to update your rules for the specific logger; give this a try:

```
<rules>
        <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />
        <logger name="kurs_ASP_dotNET___Restaurant_API.Controllers.*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="exceptions" />
        <logger name="kurs_ASP_dotNET___Restaurant_API.Middleware.RequestTimeMiddleware" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="request-time" />
        <logger name="kurs_ASP_dotNET___Restaurant_API.Services" minlevel="Error" writeTo="exceptions" />

</rules>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution doesn't work. I've fixed error logs which nlog is writing to the "exceptions" by change name in rules (I put badly name, my mistake). But Nlog still doesn't corectly write log to the "requst-time" from the RequestTimeMiddleware class.

Comment: What are the full namespace and classname for RequestTimeMiddleware? Do they match what is listed in rules?